# How can it be that a question was migrated but not an answer?

Tags: support, migration

Recently I asked and answered [My Qwest router appears to not save configuration changes. How can I fix this?](https://superuser.com/questions/616151/my-qwest-router-appears-to-not-save-configuration-changes-how-can-i-fix-this#521207). It was migrated: no problem.

However, in my notifications, it said that the question was migrated and then my answer was migrated, implying that these can be separate. How is it possible that a question can be migrated but not its answers (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got two notifications probably because the system does not care that your answer was on your own question.

Normally when a question gets migrated you get a notification saying your answer/question was migrated. Since your question got migrated you got a notification. Since your answer got migrated you got a notification. For a total of two notifications.

Comment: Exactly. It isn't possible for a mod to migrate only a question and not the answers - unless the answers were poor ones, in which case they'd be deleted first or converted to comments and then they'd be automatically migrated over with the question.  Either way they all end up getting migrated.